# How change the color of rulers in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Not sure if this feature is included in the VSCode settings yet, but I'd love to change the ruler color from it's default grey.

Tried:

```
"editor.rulers.color": "color"
```

But got an "unknown configuration setting error.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In `settings.json`:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorRuler.foreground": "#ff333388"
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me! If I want to see what other attributes of `.view-ruler` there are to change, where would I find them? For example, I would like it to be much thicker (I tried setting the `width` but it didn't change anything).

Comment: Aha! I left off `! important`, that's what it was. Thanks again!

Answer (score 60):

From the February 2020 v1.43 release, you can set per-ruler colors.  Use like this:

```
"editor.rulers": [
  {
    "column": 80,
    "color": "#ff00ff"
  },
  100,  // a ruler with the default or editorRuler.foreground color at column 100
  {
    "column": 120,
    "color": "#ff0000"
  },
],
```

See the release notes here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_43.md#multiple-rulers-with-different-colors

Comment: is there a way to have different foregrounds starting at different columns? I can do that in Atom

Comment: Do you mean the color of the text changing at different columns?  Generally no, but you could use the technique at https://stackoverflow.com/a/64247893/836330

Comment: thanks for the tip but no, actually i mean the background color. In Atom i set different background colors for different line lengths (72, 79, 119) https://snipboard.io/HsaLk4.jpg using an extension called Multi Wrap Guide https://atom.io/packages/multi-wrap-guide and some simple CSS

Comment: @lupodellasleppa I don't think there is any built-in way to do that in vscode, perhaps there is an extension.

Answer (score 3):

1. File -> Preferences -> Settings Or <kbd>cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>
2. type "rulers" and click **Edit Setings.json**

[image]
3. Add the size value by ',' As you wish

[image]

```
 "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorRuler.foreground": "#0ddf73"
  },
```

**Like this(Gif)**

[image]