# Is there any way in VSCode to show/highlight characters passing a character limit for a line?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any way in VSCode to show/highlight characters passing a character limit for a line such as 80 (possibly ignoring whitespace in the left side)? I sometimes use [Vim](https://www.vim.org), in Vim, there is a script for that. I have searched the VSCode Marketplace and have found nothing. I like to keep my code consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Highlight](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight) extension can do this.  In your settings:

```
  "highlight.regexes": {

   "(\\s*)(.{80})(.*)": {        // skip leading whitespace, skip next 80 characters

      // "filterLanguageRegex": "javascriptreact",

      "decorations": [
        {},               // do nothing to first 2 capture groups
        {},
        {
          // "outline": "green solid 2px",
          "borderWidth": "0 0 2px 0",
          "borderColor": "red",
          "borderStyle": "solid"
        },
      ]
    }
  },
```

For styling options see https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#DecorationRenderOptions

[image: 80 character limit with Highlight extension]

Comment: This is excellent! Is there a way to also add a marker to the scrollbar where the line-overruns are (so I don't have to scroll around to hunt for them)?

Answer (score 0):

This extension seems to do what you're looking for, however it doesn't seem to be very popular yet:

- ["codewall" on VS Code MarketPlace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=abhinavk99.codewall)
- [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/abhinavk99/codewall)

[image]