# VSCode: How to not show the editor ruler and instead display characters past column limit in a different color?

Tags: visual-studio-code, spacemacs, character-limit, rulers

I'm coming from spacemacs and editing Python files.

In VSCode, I want to display characters past column limit (80 characters) in a different color (red), as in Spacemacs.

I do not want to use `editor.rulers` to always show a ruler, as it's distracting.

Is this feasible?

Tried

```
    // "editor.rulers": [80],
```

But it's distracting.

Comment: Same: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64247893/836330.  Just use `"(.{80})(.*)": {` as the regex - ask if you need more help.

Comment: @Mark Actually, do you have a recommended color to use? Using `red` or `#ff0200` doesn't feel quite right compared to Spacemacs' setting.

Comment: What color does Spacemacs use?  And do you want underlining or something else?  The decoration options available are at https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#DecorationRenderOptions.