# Setting Cobol Tabs/Indents in Visual Studio Code

Tags: tabs, visual-studio-code, cobol

I have just installed Visual Studio Code on my Mac.

What is driving me crazy is my inability to set my tabs/indents to match my preferred Cobol formatting of columns 7, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24 and 72.
I have seen how to set the tab to 4 spaces, but that gives me Indents to column 5, 9 etc as it seems to tab column 1 + 4 which of course is 5 and then tab 4 spaces from there.

Answer (score 0):

I'd *guess* the options are:

- an extension that explicit does this already (you didn't specified if you use any COBOL extension for VSC or not)
- set the rulers to your preferred settings, see [Vertical rulers in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29968499/vertical-rulers-in-visual-studio-code) and "hope" you find a way to tab between these (if not: create an extension that does so)

Another option is always to use a different editor that is specialized on COBOL and may (depending on the dialect you code) even support syntax checking, like [OCIDE](https://github.com/OpenCobolIDE/OpenCobolIDE)...

Comment: The Visual Studio Code plugin called "COBOL" @ https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bitlang.cobol has support for COBOL tabstops and these can be changed via the coboleditor.tabstops settings too.