# Vertical ruler in vscode language extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, rulers

In Visual Studio Code, you can specify rulers on a [per-language basis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47784112/2950509).

When writing a language extension, how can I specify a default ruler to use? Is it even possible?