# Vertical lines in visual studio codes editor window?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have these wierd two vertical lines in VSCode editor window. What are they & how do you remove them?

[image]
https://www.diaryofacoder.com/screenshot.png

The following was in my `settings.json` file that caused the problem:

```
"editor.rulers": [
        72,50
    ],
```

Comment: They look like line length guides so you can tell if your lines of code are too long for whatever coding style you use, but they’re placed very early for that (usually the default would be 80 chars).

Comment: Possibly some extension modified the editor.rulers setting?  It is not set by default.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vertical rulers in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29968499/vertical-rulers-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Remove the `"editor.rulers": [140]` from editor settings as follows:

[image]
[image]

Comment: @coding4fun Sure! I have checked it my side and that was the issue.

Comment: out of curiosity do you know the purpose of the lines. I can't think of anything they would be helpful for....

Comment: Most code style guidelines impose limits in line lenghts to avoid the need of horizontal scroll.

Comment: @coding4fun Hi, You did not give me any update as you said!

Comment: @TanvirArjel Sorry for taking so long to report back. I just got busy with other things but yep that was the problem. Thanks for your help

Comment: @coding4fun No problem my friend! I see were away from stack overflow few days.

Comment: :(. My settings.json has no values for editor.rulers - yet there are still verticle lines!

  "editor.rulers": [
  
  ]
}