# How to add a text limit line to VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In some IDEs there is a limit line that shows maximum available symbols in row. Does anybody know extention or settings for VS Code that adds this line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the `editor.rulers` setting that draws this line. See more in [Vertical rulers in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29968499/vertical-rulers-in-visual-studio-code)