# Vertical column in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am moving my development to VSCode and I would like to know how to set a vertical column instead of vertical rulers as explained in [Vertical rulers in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29968499/2971299):

What I have:
[image]

What I want is the vertical column to be solid (screenshot from vim column):
[image]

**UPDATE**

I actually spend some time after @bgse suggestion and found all the places that have to be modified to enable this feature. See the green arrows below.

[image]

`box-shadow` parameter limits the size of the shaded area for all rulers. By default vscode sets it to [1px](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/d4789ac7c9d9f73865ca92f8b1d67be5d5a4c283/src/vs/editor/browser/viewParts/rulers/rulers.ts#L105). After increasing it (manually), one can increase (manually) the `width` of the `view-ruler` element.

Any chance to change these parameters from the settings.json file?

Answer (score 2):

You can't currently do that with just settings and color theme to the best of my knowledge.

There is an extension mentioned in the comments of the linked question answers that allows to adjust the thickness of the indent lines among other things, but nothing similar for the editor rulers on marketplace it seems.

For what it's worth, the CSS you'd want to touch specifically is `.monaco-editor .view-ruler` box shadow.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The code to generate the rullers seems simple, but with my limited knowledge of CSS and HTML I could not make it look the way I wanted. Not even in the debug mode.
I will leave the code for view-ruler here `https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/master/src/vs/editor/browser/viewParts/rulers` in case someone wants to venture on adding this feature. This code inserts this line for the sytle `.monaco-editor .view-ruler { box-shadow: 1px 0 0 0 #979797 inset; }` Playing with box-shadow can modify the ruler thickness to some extent

Comment: I actually investigated a little further and found a way to hack it in (see the update in question). Suggestions on how to automate it are welcome.