# How to hide vertical line in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

In my vscode there is vertical line. I can't find to hide it. Please see in attached. I have already disabled minimap. [image]

Comment: [Vertical rulers in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29972073) Set `editor.rulers: []`

Comment: Or just delete that `editor.rulers` setting.

Answer (score 1):

if you're using Flutter then you need to edit the ruler for dart, you'll navigate to the file from RUN command: %APPDATA%\code\User\settings.json

and set the ruler to 0 like in the picture attached.

[settings.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccnoI.png)