# What is the name of this line in Atom editor and how to have it in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, atom-editor

[image]

What is the name of the line that you're seeing in the picture above in Atom editor?
And how to have it in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29972073/12098106

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VS Code it's called a *ruler* (AKA *column guide(line)* / *indent guide* / *wrap guide* in other editors). You can configure them using the `editor.rulers` setting:

```json
"editor.rulers": [80, 100],
```

or with colors:

```json
"editor.rulers": [
    { "column": 80, "color": "#88776655" },
    { "column": 100, "color": "#ff887766" },
],
```