# How to force line character length width in a .Net project

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, roslyn-code-analysis, stylecop

In the project I am working on, I am tasked with forcing line character width to 140 characters for a line of code in the visual studio editor. Unfortunately, to my research, any roslyn based analyzer does not support this feature.
Can you please lead me a way to achieve this, it could be writing custom rules or what?

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean with "line"?

Is this a file or textarea or Some another thing?

Thanks

Comment: A line of code in the VS Editor.

Comment: See: [Adding a guideline to the editor in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84209/adding-a-guideline-to-the-editor-in-visual-studio).

Comment: There's a long standing [open issue](https://github.com/dotnet/format/issues/246) about supporting EditorConfig's `max_line_length`/`rulers` in `dotnet format`

Answer (score 1):

You could add the Editor Guidelines extension into Visual Studio:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PaulHarrington.EditorGuidelines

I find it helpful to visually limit the length of lines of code, but it's not an automatic enforcement.